# UIPicker and UIActionsheet no longer working iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, uipickerview

Hi My UI Picker no longer works on iOS7, it pops up but it is blank. Only happened on iOS7.

```
//picker
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
animationsLabel.text = [optionsArray objectAtIndex:[picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];

if (pickerView==animationsPicker) {
    animationsLabel.text = [optionsArray objectAtIndex:[animationsPicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
}

}
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [optionsArray count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
   return [optionsArray objectAtIndex:row];
   NSLog(@"title options array %lu",(unsigned long)optionsArray.count);
}
```

And the action:

```
-(IBAction)animationActionSheet:(id)sender {

UIActionSheet *selectPopup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                          destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                               otherButtonTitles:nil];

[selectPopup showInView:self.view];

optionsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"6",@"5",@"7",@"8",@"9", nil];

// Create picker
animationsPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 160, 320, 100)];
animationsPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
[self.view addSubview:animationsPicker];
animationsPicker.delegate = self;
animationsPicker.dataSource = self;
[selectPopup addSubview:animationsPicker];

// Animate picker opening
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[selectPopup setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This is what I have tried so far. There was never a problem displaying the picker in the an Action sheet before, but now it is blank. Im wondering did anyone else come across this problem, or can you see any errors? I printed everything to do with the picker.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was told that putting pickers in Action Sheets was non-standard.  I never had any problems doing this in iOS 6, but in iOS 7, I got errors.  I switched to UIView instead of action sheets for my pickers and it works fine.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was hoping that wouldnt be the case, but it should be simples to fix. I was hoping to keep it the same. Thanks again.

Comment: I was hoping that too, but it's not bad to put them in UIViews instead of ActionSheets.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Adding subviews is not recommended for the action sheet, per documentation.

> "Subclassing Notes
>   UIActionSheet is not designed to be subclassed, nor should you add views to its hierarchy. If you need to present a sheet with more customization than provided by the UIActionSheet API, you can create your own and present it modally with presentViewController:animated:completion:."

Apple is reinforcing their usage for Action Sheets....and they upped the ante for this to work in iOS 7, which means you have to code around it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this project I made. It's practically the same thing as having a picker inside an action sheet https://github.com/DiscoverPioneer/PickerSlider